# When is a monic endomorphism epic?

Tags: category-theory

It is elementary that an injective map from a finite set to itself is surjective, and from the rank-nullity theorem, an injective map from a finite dimensional vector space to itself is also surjective.  Further, by the Ax-Grothendieck theorem, an injective polynomial map $p:\mathbb C^n \to \mathbb C^n$ is surjective.

Is there any sort of categorical framework for this?  Any characterization or sufficient condition where monic endomorphisms are epic?  Perhaps something along the lines of "If a category satisfies property $P$, then the compact objects have all self-monics are epic." Baring this, are there any other interesting or useful examples where the property holds?

Comment: You might want to see [this](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2010/REUPapers/Laackman.pdf).

Comment: @Ennar Thanks.  While not directly relevant (though in parts very close), it was an interesting read.

Comment: Yes, not exactly the same thing, but Dedekind finiteness is almost what you are looking for (a bit stronger since you want bimorphisms, not isomorphisms).

Comment: Yes, Dedekind finiteness is close to the property I described, and having a name gives me a useful jumping off point for further research.

Comment: Do you *really* want epis? E.g. for algebras (sets, vector spaces, groups, rings, lattices, ...) we have "surjective $=$ regular epi $=$ extremal epi $\neq$ epi".

Comment: @StefanPerko I'm honestly not sure.  It's hard for me to generalize from three examples, and in the case of polynomial maps from $\mathbb C^n$ to itself, I'm not actually sure if surjective corresponds to epi.  I suppose that my question is, "Here is a notion that seems to encode some sense of smallness or finiteness, but which I've not seen discussed.  What is the right notion, and when does it coincide with other categorical notions of smallness?"  Or maybe that's not even quite the right question.  I'm asking out of pure curiosity, not because I need it for something.

Comment: @Aaron My point was: If you have an object, such that all endo monic's are *extremal* epi, then it is already Dedekind finite (because "extremal epi $+$ mono $=$ iso"). This is the case for finite sets and finite dimensional vector spaces (I don't know anything about your last example though). So this is the notion you are looking for *unless* you can come up with an interesting example where "mono $+$ endo $\Rightarrow$ epi", which is not a Dedekind finite object. The difference comes down to the question "Is this epi also extremal?", basically.